# What kinds of smartness does Tom Sawyer in "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer" have? "street smart" or "smart aleck"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-request, word-meaning, phrase-request

I guess most American or British people have read "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer".

Tom Sawyer in "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer" is smart but not book-smart.

Once, his aunt punished him by telling him to paint a long fence. He didn't want to do that.

While he was painting the fence, he saw Ben, one of his friends, coming up to him and at that moment he had a smart idea.

He told Ben that painting is fun and said if Ben gave him some toy he would let him paint the fence. And Ben accepted.

There a lot of people like Tom in reality. They are very smart but their smartness tend to be some kind of trickery.

They are smart but they don't care about the feeling of others. Other people might or might not recognize their intentions. For example, Ben in the story didn't recognize Tom's bad intention.

My question is that.

**Do we have an adjective to express that trickery smart (smart in a way that care about oneself only and hurt others or not care about feeling of others)?**

There are "**street smart**" or "**smart aleck**", but I don't understand their meanings.

Also, I would appreciate if you could give me some examples to understand "**street smart**" or "**smart aleck**".

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions?

Comment: @gotube,  i did but I need examples that help me to understand their meanings.

Comment: I asked because "smart aleck" isn't even close to the story of Tom Sawyer and the fence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Street smart' is really a modern term, not applicable to Tom Sawyer. It's an urban term, literally being smart about how things work on the urban streets.
'Smart alec' is a derisory term, used for someone who tends to show off, speak  as though knowledgeable, without having the actual knowledge to back that up. The 'smart' doesn't imply 'intelligence'.
Wise guy [or ass] etc also doesn't imply actual wisdom. Colloquially, it implies "more mouth than brain".

I would call Sawyer's 'smarts' "**low [cunning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cunning)**". Cunning alone is "the ability to achieve things in a clever way, often by deceiving other people". The addition of 'low' reduces this still further, morally.

Comment: Concering "smart alec", note that a "wise ass" usually isn't very wise, either!

Comment: Yeah - wise guy [wise anything] implies 'more mouth than brain' too.

Comment: Do American people say "**low cunning**"?